# Infinity limits using definition

Tags: calculus

Prove using the definition

$$\lim_{x \to 0-} \frac{1}{x}$$

Definition :

To all M>0 exists $\delta>0$ so to all x that appiles $-\delta<x<0$ appiles $\frac{1}{x}<-M$

EDIT:

$$\frac{1}{-\delta}\leq -M$$ 
$$1\geq -M*-\delta$$
$$\frac{1}{-M} \leq -\delta$$
$$\frac{1}{M} \geq \delta$$

That's looks odd that any $\delta$ **bigger** than $\frac{1}{M}$ is suitable, since I'm pretty sure that exist a really huge $\delta$ that isn't suitable for M, it just not sounds intuitive right. Maybe my way of solving it was wrong? In case not, Could anyone explain this intuitive?

Thanks.

Comment: When multiplying an inequality by a negative [term], the sign should be flipped; it should be $1\geq-M\cdot-\delta$

Comment: Though it would change back to $\leq$ in the next line, as you are [dividing] by $-M$.

Comment: Oh.. So it actually should be $$\frac{1}{M} \geq \delta$$? right?

Comment: Yup. Luckily, two wrongs made a right!

Answer (score 0):

We want to prove that:

> $$
> \lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{1}{x} = -\infty 
> $$

Now given any $M > 0$, let $\delta = \frac{1}{M}$ (which is positive). Now suppose that $-\delta < x < 0$. Then by examining the first half of this inequality and taking reciprocals of both sides, it follows that $\frac{1}{-\delta} > \frac{1}{x}$. But then observe that:
$$
\frac{1}{x} < \frac{1}{-\delta} = \frac{1}{-\frac{1}{M}} = -M
$$
as desired. $~~\blacksquare$